# Como construir a expressão regular para o caso?

Tags: regex

Preciso criar uma expressão para o seguinte caso de um campo de código:

- Não há quantidade de caracteres máximos
- O primeiro dígito deve ser apenas números [0-9]
- O código é composto de dígitos alfanuméricos e apenas os caracteres / (barra) e - (hífen), e nem sempre terão todos eles.

Tentei iniciar uma, porém sem sucesso:

```
^[0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\/-]+$
```

Exemplo de resultados

válidos:

```
260509
8605/05
5ABC605/05
756574-7
88BS-AS0
```

Inválidos:

```
A8605/05
B756574-7
```

Comment: Qual problema você está tendo Marcelo? Eu testei sua regex e funcionou, claro que ela pode ser melhorada mas você relatou que não tinha funcionado e ao testar tudo funcionou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que esse regex serve para capturar o padrão desejado:

```
^\d([\w\-/]*)
```

Ela significa, o primeiro caracter deve ser um número, seguido de um grupo que contenha uma lista de caracateres a-zA-Z0-9_-/

Comment: faltou uma barra \ antes da /, ^\d([\w\-\/]*)

Comment: @ErickGallani eu testei no notepad++ e como não foi especificada linguagem não escapei essa barra :P, dependendo da linguagem é precisa sim como vc falou.

Comment: se o hífen for o último caractere da classe não precisa ser escapado: `^\d([\w/-]*)`

Comment: Pelo menos nos testes online, só capturou o primeiro valor `260509`, @rray

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade você está tentando usar no javascript essa regex? Caso sim você precisa fazer o seguinte /^\d([\w\-\/]*)/gm (g = de global e m = multilines)

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade tem o link p teste? qual linguagem vc usou?

Comment: @Sanção não sabia isso, valeu a dica :)

Comment: @rray a sim, dependendo da linguagem não precisa mesmo é que eu sempre acabo testando no https://regex101.com/ que usa javascript como padrão kkk

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade veja o exemplo funcionando https://regex101.com/r/aV7fV5/1

Comment: Sim e outra coisa o @ErickGallani, ligou `g` e o `m` matching global e para várias linhas.

Comment: Aqui ó: https://regex101.com/r/kP8tL9/1

Comment: Agora funcionou após ligar `g` e `m`.

Comment: No javascript, como ficaria a regex para que o se não der match no input, ele esteja incorreto?

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade, chama assim: `input.match(/^\d([\w\/-]*)/g)` e joga em um if, ele vai retornar um booleano.

Comment: Obrigado, @rray. Eu me expressei erroneamente, o que precisaria é desse match invertido. O controle está direto no input: `this.value=this.value.replace(/^\d([\w\/-]*)/g,'')`

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade, confundi tudo haha não entendi nada, poderia explicar novamente :)

Comment: Fiz [outra questão](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/94254/como-criar-express%C3%A3o-para-permitir-apenas-alguns-caracteres) detalhando.