# Como criar expressão para permitir apenas alguns caracteres?

Tags: javascript, regex

Estou a criar um input onde um onKeyUp verifica os caracteres inseridos, ele deve validar o seguinte:

- Não há quantidade de caracteres máximos
- O primeiro dígito deve ser apenas números [0-9]
- O código é composto de dígitos alfanuméricos e apenas os caracteres / (barra) e - (hífen), e nem sempre terão todos eles.

válidos:

```
260509
8605/05
5ABC605/05
756574-7
88BS-AS0
```

Inválidos:

```
A8605/05
B756574-7
```

Utilizando a expressão:

```
/^\d([\w\/-]*)/gm
```

Eu consigo dar match nos valores de forma correta, porém preciso inseri-lo na função:

```
this.value=this.value.replace(/^\d([\w\/-]*)/gm,'')
```

Mas a função deve ter o funcionamento invertido, quando não der match, substituir por " ".

Comment: Será que é uma boa ideia fazer isso no keyUp? Veja [essa pergunta](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9205164/520779) que postei no SOen há bastante tempo, e [essa resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9205475/520779) em particular. Dito isso, é possível sim fazer uma expressão como a que você quer, vou postar em breve como resposta.

Comment: Eu não acho que seja @mgibsonbr, porém é exigência do cliente.

Comment: Eu estou um pouco confuso com esse `m` - a entrada é um conjunto de códigos separados por quebras de linha, ou a substituição ocorrerá linha por linha?

Comment: Acredito que o `m` pode ser retirado, pois o valor será um único código digitado no input.

Comment: Efetuando a substituição do método `replace` por `match`, ocorreu o resultado esperado porém não tenho certeza se é a solução ideal: `this.value=this.value.match(/^\d([\w\/-]*)/g);`

Comment: É uma possibilidade, mas se houver um caractere inválido no meio do caminho ele vai dividir o campo em dois. Ex.: `123$567`

Comment: Ele não permitiu inserir um caractere fora do match, não entendi como mas funcionou.

Comment: Experimente copiar o exemplo acima e colar no campo com o seu código. Ele vai ser substituído por `123`, e não por `123567`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema de validar enquanto o usuário digita é que é necessário não que o campo inteiro seja válido mas que um **prefixo** do mesmo o seja (pois senão o usuário nunca ia conseguir acabar de digitar, a menos que colasse o valor inteiro com Ctrl+V), e somente no final uma validação do campo completo pode ser feita. No seu caso entretanto é fácil, já que somente um único dígito é obrigatório e os demais são opcionais:

```js
document.querySelector("input").onkeyup = function(e) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/^\D.*|[^\w\/-]/gm,'');
}
```

```html
<input>
```

Esse código elimina o campo inteiro se o primeiro dígito não for um número, ou elimina cada caractere específico que não esteja no conjunto dado (i.e. seu conjunto de caracteres permitidos, negado). Se o usuário colar o campo de algum outro lugar, somente os caracteres válidos permanecerão.

A principal desvantagem desse método é que ele não preserva o *caret*. Seria altamente desejável que o usuário pudesse voltar com as setas e corrigir um trecho incorreto, mas isso complicaria um pouco as coisas.

Nota: essa resposta assume que somente *o trecho incorreto* deve ser eliminado na substituição, não o código inteiro - caso contrário, se o usuário estivesse digitando e acidentalmente entrasse com um caractere inválido, e o campo todo sumisse, acho que ele não ia ficar muito satisfeito...

Comment: A solução funciona corretamente, exceto no bendito IE. Infelizmente preciso que funcione nele também. Quando o valor inserido no input não dá match, ele insere NULL no campo e não permite nem mesmo apagar. Saberia o motivo disto ocorrer?

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade Infelizmente eu só tenho o IE11 pra testar, e que eu saiba a partir do IE9 as expressões regulares funcionam sem problemas. Não sei como fazer pra funcionar no IE8 ou anterior, o jeito pode ser testar o valor de retorno por NULL e, se for, não fazer a substituição (sendo um browser em versão antiga, creio que seu cliente vai aceitar a limitação).